# Pandas - compare two date time column fails (while checking whether both the columns are empty)

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing two datetime64[ns] columns and it returns an error - 
**raise TypeError("Cannot change data-type for object array.")**

Both the a_col and b_col are datetime64[ns] and have NaN's in them.

```
df[res] = (df[a_col] == df[b_col]) | (df[[a_col, b_col]].isnull().any(axis=1))
```

What I am trying in the above code is, Return True if the dates match and also return True if both the values are empty in both the columns.

The Issue seems to be occurring on the second part of the line -

```
(df[[a_col, b_col]].isnull().any(axis=1))
```

So, I think this has a lot to do with NaN's.

Comment: It was a typo made on the question. I will change it now

Comment: Can you cut the problem into two : check the expected result for (df[a_col] == df[b_col]) and the expected one for (df[[a_col, b_col]].isnull().any(axis=1)). You will see which one is not working

Comment: The second part is not working - (df[[a_col, b_col]].isnull().any(axis=1))

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should be using `.all(1)` if you want to require both are missing.

Comment: @ALollz How do you do that, I am sorry. I don't get it.

Comment: Your second condition is True if df['a_col'] is null, *or* df['b_col'] is null, *or* both of them are null (because you are using `.any()`). From your description you want to require that both are null, so you should be checking `.all()`

Comment: ah get you now. But, that doesn't fix this Issue. Thanks for the KT on a concept.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2bcW.png) seems to work like you wanted